# Material Ui Avatar add elevation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I try to add elevation(shadow) to a MUI Avatar component https://material-ui.com/components/avatars/#image-avatars.

```
<Avatar alt="Cindy Baker" src="/static/images/avatar/3.jpg" />
```

Wrapping the Avatar with `paper` or `Card` increases the radius.

I also tried setting `boxShadow` of the Avatar using makeStyles and MUI shadow https://material-ui.com/system/shadows/ but without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tested, and it works with shadow. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles'
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar'

export default () => {

    const classes = useClasses()

    return (
        <Avatar
            className={classes.avatar}
            alt="Cindy Baker"
            src="/static/images/avatar/3.jpg"
        />
    )
}

const useClasses = makeStyles(theme => ({
    avatar: {
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[3],
    }
}))
```

Comment: ahh... I thought I had to import shadows... thanks for clarification. In the meantime I found a different solution (below) but thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, any solution is good , as long as it works :)

Answer (score 3):

Found an alternative solution myself:

```
<Avatar component={Paper} elevation={2}>
    <DirectionsCarIcon />
</Avatar>
```